# Django Annotate - Concat from last created ManyToMany Object Fields

Tags: mysql, django, orm, prefetch, annotate

```
class User(models.Model):
    name=CharField()


class Address(models.Model):
    user= Foreignkey(user, related_name="Addresses")
    buildingname=CharField()
    street=CharField()
    ...
```

I have a models like top and want to extract data as list below.

```
{
    [
        ['USERNAME1', 'A XYZBUILDING 14 Drain St. '],
        ['USERNAME2', 'C XXXBUILDING 13 Drain St. '],
        ['USERNAME3', 'B ZZZBUILDING 12 Drain St. '],
        ...
    ]
    
}
```

Also as a workaround, this is a closest thing to the answer but i could not make it finish

**without looping every user** or

**without executing raw sql in extra method's select field**.

I want to achive this with Django ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution probably, but it covers the requirements.

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, CharField, Value, F, OuterRef
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce, Trim, Concat

from myfile import my_custom_filters, Address, User

address_subquery = Address.objects.filter(
    user__id=OuterRef('id')
).order_by('-created')
User.objects.filter(**my_custom_filters).annotate(
    street_str=Subquery(
        Coalesce(
            address_subquery.values_list('street', flat=True)[:1], 
            Value("")
        ),
        output_field=CharField()
    ),
    building_name_str=Subquery(
        Coalesce(
            address_subquery.values_list('building_name', flat=True)[:1], 
            Value("")
        ),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).annotate(
    address_text_str=Trim(
        Concat(
            F('street_str'),
            Value(" "),
            F('building_name_str')
        )
    )
).values_list('name', 'address_text_str')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing wrong in subquery, you have to write subquery like this :-

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef

address_subquery = Address.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('created')
```

You can refer from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions